# How can I erase characters previously written on console?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'm building a basic login program, that uses ReadKey to store and then compare with a pre-saved password. Since every instance of ReadKey also prints `'*'`, and that I need to be able to backspace to correct the password, I'm finding it hard to delete the `'*'` I wrote before in the console. How can I do this?

I've found a way to modify the string I'm working with but this is stalling me.

Comment: Do you really need `ReadKey`? What's wrong with `ReadLn`?

Answer (score 2):

(from memory) usually something like

gotoxy(wherex-1,wherey);